# Comparison of between hours using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

In my application I want to determine if a `hour:minute` is bigger than 21:00h and other `hour:minute` is lesser than 08:00.

I am using the [24-hour format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) for this.

```
var one = "21:30";
var two = "09:51";
```

To get just hour from hour and minutes I use `split()`:

```
var h_1 = one.split(":"); //21
var h_2 = two.split(":"); //08

    if (h_1 > "21" && h_2 < "08") {
        // Do something
    }
```

The real story for the application is:
A shop has an option to deliver outside of working time (working hours start at "08:00" - "21:00").

If a customer wants to buy out of hours, `do something`.

So why does my approach not work properly? What is the best approach to compare the hours and minutes between two variables of h:m type?

Comment: Where are you plucking your `h1` and `h2` variables from?

Comment: `if(h1 > "21" && h2 < "08") {` should be `if(h_1 > "21" && h_2 < "08") {` to start with.

Comment: @MattLishman Or rather `if(h_1[0] >= "21" && h_2[0] <= "08")`

Comment: What is `takeHour[0]` and `backHour[0]`?

Comment: `one.split(":")` gives an array, not a value

Comment: `takeHour[0]` is array item from split

Comment: @George You're right, that answers the question, I was just fixing the code example. :0

Comment: I give just example what i need `if(hour1 > "21:00" && hour2 < "08:00") // do somthing`\.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried comparing the strings?

```
if (two < "08:00" && one > "21:00")  
  //magic
```

As long as your strings are always formatted with a leading zero for one-digit hours, then it woks fine.

Comment: @Zend, it seems like what you WANT is to see if the time that the user is entering, to compare that single value as an "OR": `if (cust_time < "08:00" || cust_time > "21:00")`, but that's not what you asked for.

Comment: @Paul Roub Thanks for the editing changes. My previous forum experience has left a few bad habits, such as the "edit: blah blah"

Answer (score 0):

The **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method return an array, so to get just hours (first column in your case) you should specify index `0`:

```
var h_1 = one.split(":")[0]; //21
var h_2 = two.split(":")[0]; // 08
```

> i want to determine if hour:minute one is biger than 21:00h and hour:minute two is lesser than 08:00

Use greater than or equal to operator `>=` and less than or equal to `<=` to exclude hours `21` and `08`:

```
if(h_1 >= "21" && h_2 <= "08") {
    // do somthing
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `if(h1 >= "21" && h2 <= "08") {` should be `if(h_1 >= "21" && h_2 <= "08") {`

Comment: This won't work without a parseInt though, right? Also you are checking if an integer is less than the string "21". So : `if(parseInt(h_1) >= 21 && parseInt(h_2) <= 8)` instead?

Comment: NO, not true @MattLishman JS will take care of that without using `parseInt`. you could test it...

Comment: Okay, I tested it and it worked. I take back what I said. However, _why_ use a string? Why make JS do the conversion?

Comment: The question is why we should use `parseInt` when we're getting strings and we could compare them directly and let JS do it work?